# Smooth first derivative of noisy input signal

Tags: c++, filtering, smoothing

I have attached images of an input signal (shown in blue), which is actually a continuous input stream and whose trend I do not know, and the signal smoothed using a moving average filter of span 5 (shown in red).

**Raw input and smoothed input signal**

[image]

**First derivative of the raw input and smoothed input signal**

[image]

My aim is to calculate the ratio of this signal to its first derivative. However, clearly the first derivative is noisy and does not give good results. I realize I must change the filter from moving average to a more robust one. 
I have looked up Savitzky-Golay filter, but I read on another site that it is more efficient in retaining the shape of the signal than reducing the noise. http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/Smoothing.html

Kalman filter would be my next guess but it needs an initial state estimate which I cannot know for this type of signal.

Any other suggestions on how to smooth the first derivative of a noisy input?

Comment: If you know the physics behind your signals, you may fit the analytical model function (exponent?) to your raw data, and then perform all the operations on that smooth fitted function.

Comment: That's my problem. I do not know the model of this function. It could be quadratic, cubic, exponential by looking at this data. Since this is a continuous stream of input, I will not have all the data to perform fitting on. Carrying out fitting every time I receive an input can prove to be computationally expensive, especially on-board a UAV.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't expect any miracles from any of these filters. Numerical differentiation of noisy data is generally critical because the differentialtion operation itself acts as a high pass filter and thus amplifies noise.

Yes there are differences between Moving Average, Savitzky-Golay and Kalman but these are subtle. The main advantage of Savitzky-Golay is using an adaptive window size.

Looking at your data, it seems like you should use a much larger window size resulting in a lower cut-off frequency. But then, I don't know if your data sets always look like this.

Another hint: As long as your filters are effectively linear, it does not matter if you first apply the filter and then calculate the derivative or if you calculate the derivative from the original signal and then apply the filtering.

Comment: My ideal dataset would look like this. Although, this is only a small portion and with more time, the trend may vary from the seemingly quadratic trend at present. Also, I do need both the smooth input and its derivative for my calculations. Would it be advisable to smooth the raw input using the moving average filter and then calculate the derivative of the smooth signal and smooth this derivative further with a Savitzky-Golay filter?

Comment: Yes, in this case you probably want more smoothing in the derivative. I don't think the specific types of filters will make a significant difference, but if you have them already implemented, just try it out.